# How to add infotip for files in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I know how to add an info tip to folders using the desktop.ini file, but how do I show comments when I hover over a particular file?

Comment: http://www.dwindlingthumbs.com/tidbits/how-to-add-comments-to-files-and-folders/ seems to be usefull

Answer (score 0):

- right click on the file
- select Properties
- open Details tab
- Enter information into Comments
- Click OK
- Hover mouse over file

Doesn't work for all files. But most